# How to reference a custom Dockerfile located in a sibling folder in Tiltfile?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am not able to reference a custom Dockerfile that is located in a folder that is sibling to the folder containing my Tiltfile

docker_build('foo-image', '../foo/', dockerfile='Dockerfile.custom')

It keeps looking the Dockerfile.custom file in the directory where the Tiltfile is located

Answer (score 0):

The actual way of doing it was by using the ".." in the dockerfile option

```
docker_build('foo-image', '../foo', dockerfile='../foo/Dockerfile.custom')
```